# Billing solution for a Video On Demand App on Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am in the process of building a Video On Demand kind of app for Android which is very similar to what Google Play Movies with a few differences.

I am done with most of the things for the app and now I am deciding upon the billing strategy for renting out movies from this app. By looking at Google Play Movies I found that if you rent a movie there, you are given a period of 48 hours from when you start watching the movie. I want to understand that is such a billing strategy possible using the In App Billing method already available for Android.

As far as I understand and have tried out, In App Billing is applicable to a list of products that I define in the developer console and the users consume but for a VOD kind of app where my video listing would change from time to time, this might not be the best strategy and might not be even applicable.

If that is the case then how are things working with the Google Play Movies?
Can anyone throw some light on what other options i might have of making the user experience as close as possible to what Google Play movies provides.

I have also explored other payment options of third party payment processors like Zooz and a few others but in my opinion of Google Play Movies is using In App Purchase or Google Checkout interface then is it possible for my app to use the same and if yes any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you've worked out, you wouldn't have one IAP product per film. But you might have one product which is a single 48-hour rental, and the user buys this product and then cashes it in within your app to rent the actual film.

Really, it's the Google Play terms that decide this question for you. If the thing you're selling is only accessible within your app, then you *must* use Google Play's IAP functionality. If the sale is usable from outside the app (e.g. you can buy a rental on Android and then watch the film via a web browser on any device), then you shouldn't use IAP. This is all explained in the terms.

None of the parts of Google Play use the public IAP interface, even though they all go through the same billing system in the end.

Comment: Dan, I cannot have one single product which is a rental for 48 hours. The simple reason is that every movie in the app might have a different pricing. Further, the movies bought from the app would be viewable only from within the app and not outside. Thanks for explaining things though. Can you shed some more light on what other approach i might take?

Comment: There are lots of ways. You could use an in-app currency, like most microtransaction-based games have. You could have one IAP product per price point ("premium movie", "budget movie", "TV episode", "TV series" &c.). The details will of course depend on your particular situation, so you'll have to think for yourself about what fits.